# Wordpress output using custom url

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I've been using WP_Route to create some custom urls as:

```
domain.com/players/playerID
```

If I use wp_send_json with a query result it works fine, but I would like to print that result.

If  I do an :

```
get_header();
echo "<h1>".$player->name."</h1>";
get_footer();
```

I get:

```
NAME 

OOPS! THAT PAGE CAN’T BE FOUND
```

any clues?
How could I force WP to don't run content hooks/whatever ?
PS: Wp_die() adds another header and body tag after the "good content".

```
<body id="error-page">
<p></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Anthony Budd's [WP_Route](https://github.com/anthonybudd/WP_Route), then don't. It's not a finished product ([it doesn't work](https://github.com/anthonybudd/WP_Route/issues/5)). It's surprising that the author has [pushed](https://medium.com/@AnthonyBudd/wp-route-a-simple-way-to-make-custom-routes-in-wordpress-5ab1b3063115) this class without even testing it. Other users have made [pull requests](https://github.com/anthonybudd/WP_Route/pulls), presumably fixing some of the bugs and glaring omissions, but it seems that the author isn't responding so consider the project dead. There are forks, however, that might be in working condition.

You should probably just [`exit;`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) in your handler.

When you call the `wp_die()` function it typically outputs a full HTML document, including the `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags as well as some CSS and an error message, and this is probably not what you want in your handler.

As the WP_Route class is written, your handler is executed on the WordPress [init](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/) hook.

Comment: Ended up with laravel and a subdomain!